Iodoform test for ethanol?
I understand the iodoform test can be used to determine methyl ketones, but why can it also be used to determine secondary alcohols? Does the iodine act as an oxidising agent to oxidise the secondary alcohol to a ketone? Whats even more confusing is why iodoform can determine ethanol. Ethanol doesn't have a methyl ketone, so why does it give a positive result. Why is ethanol the only primary alcohol that gives a positive result? Why not methanol or propanol or butanol? I am confused.

What does the iodoform reaction test for? Look at the mechanism if you are unsure. And what does ethanAl have that methanal, propanal... lack? And how might iodine react with an alcohol?

Iodine in the presence of hydroxide gives hypoiodate which oxidises ethanol to acetaldehyde.

Iodine in basic solution can oxidize ethanol to acetadehyde, which as $\ce{H – C(O) – CH3}$ then acts as a methyl ketone.
